# scipy can't optimize parameters gives error- RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in reduce

Tags: python, scipy

I'm trying to optimize parameters using data for my model with scipy optimize but scipy fails to minimize the function and find values of the parameters. It just returns the initial guess which the user gives as input.Also, it gives the following error: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in reduce.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from math import log10
import math
import scipy.optimize as op
from scipy.integrate import odeint

df1 = pd.read_csv('dataset1.csv')
z=df1.loc[: , "z"]
za=z.as_matrix(columns=None)
mu=df1.loc[: , "mu"]
mua=mu.as_matrix(columns=None)
si=df1.loc[: , "sig"]
sia=si.as_matrix(columns=None)

c = 299792.458;
H0 = 70;
m_t=0.3
d_t=0.7
mu0 = 25 + 5*log10(c/H0);

def model(x,t,m,d):
    dydt = 1/(math.sqrt((((1+x)**2)*(1+m*x))-(x*d*(2+x))))
    return dydt

def Io(zb,m,d):
    return odeint(model,0,zb, args=(m,d))

def lnlike(theta,zb, mub,sib):
    m, d = theta
    isia2 = 1.0/np.square(sib)
    return 0.5*(np.sum(((((5*(np.log10((1+zb)*Io(zb,m,d)))+mu0)-mub)**2)*isia2)- np.log(isia2)))

nll = lambda *args: -lnlike(*args)
result = op.minimize(nll, [m_t, d_t], args=(za, mua,sia))
m_ml, d_ml = result["x"]
print(m_ml, d_ml)
```

I think scipy is not able to handle illegal values generated due to the square root.If so, how can one bypass the illegal values?

the dataset1 file can be found at the link:https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HDzQ7rz_u9y63ECNkhtB49T2KBvu0qu6/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The easiest solution may be to simply ignore the warning, because it is just a warning, not an error. If only certain parameter ranges are allowed (e.g. only positive values) add bounds or constraints. Otherwise, you can simply add something like this to the objective function: `if value_passed_to_sqrt < 0: return some_reasonable_value`. (Note that `np.log` may also issue this warning.)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.But, I should have mentioned earlier that scipy fails to minimize the function and find values of the parameters. It just returns the initial guess which the user gives as input. This is the main problem which I thought was due to the illegal values. Sorry for being evasive.